# Adding video bytes to buffer in iOS native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

Is it possible within a native iOS app to play video by downloading a segment of video and inserting or appending it's bytes to some kind of buffer, ready for playback?

Something similar to the way HLS works, but at a lower level where I can control exactly which segments are loaded and when they are appended.

(If you have any knowledge of other platforms, I'm looking for something similar to Javascript's [SouceBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298840.aspx) or Actionscript's [NetStream.appendBytes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes()))

Comment: Look up VideoToolbox in the ios8 documentation.